# Vim C++ compile Command

Tags: c++, vim, c++17, neovim

I want to know about this command for C++ file compilation in vim text Editor.

**autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap  :w  !g++ -std=c++17 % -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLOCAL -o %:r -Wl,--**stack,268435456****

What is the use of this **--stack,268435456** in the above command ?
Why my computer freezes when my code runs in a infinite LOOP ?

PS - This is the command copied from other computer vimrc.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `--stack,268435456` sets the stack size to 256 MB

Comment: you cleared my doubts

Answer (score 0):

Short version, in two files.

```
" file: ~/.vimrc
" To activate ftplugins
" you may already have 'filetype plugin indent on', it's good as well
filetype plugin on

" To make sure to compile with warnings and in C++17
" You don't need anything else
let $CXXFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra -std=c++17'
" and don't forget warnings in C either
let $CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra'


" file ~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim
" it'll also be used for C++
nnoremap <buffer> <F7>   :<c-u>w|make %<<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> <C-F5> :<c-u>./%<<cr>
```

And then hit `F7` to compile, and `CTRL+F5` to execute -- you can use anything else.

To navigate error messages, you'll need `:copen`, `:cc`, `:cnext`, `:cclose`... in short, read documentation about Vim `:h quickfix` feature.

A little but longer version: https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/project/doc/make_run.md#mono-file-projects

Regarding other parameters you've *stolen* they probably make sense for the person who is/was using them (set a macro, change stack size (I guess)). By default, you don't need them.

Comment: I ran an infinite loop in this stack of size 256 MB and my computer freezes